# Tweak the gui by expanding panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a pdf viewer but I can't separate view from tabbed pane. I tried everything but not success,

- I tried adding ***JSplit*** pane, not it didn't work. (I don't need to add it now, just need to expand the right side panel.
- And I tried adjusting size of panels using `setSize(x, y)`. But it didn't work either.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Here some code:

```
class Main
{   
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pdf Reader");
        frame.setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new LeftPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new ViewPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class LeftPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JPanel panel4;

    public LeftPanel(){
        addTabs();  
    }

    public void addTabs()
    {   
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        panel1 = new JPanel();  
        tabs.addTab("Thumbnails", panel1);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        tabs.addTab("Annotations", panel2);

        panel3 = new JPanel();
        tabs.addTab("Bookmarks", panel3);

        panel4 = new JPanel();
        tabs.addTab("Search", panel4);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class ViewPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel viewLabel;

    public ViewPanel(){

        viewLabel = new JLabel("Just a view...............................");

        add(viewLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the issue with JSplitPane

Comment: How can I expand right side of panel(viewpanel) and tweak the gui.

Comment: just position the divider by calling splitPane.setDividerLocation()

Comment: Ok, then does it change sizes of Panels between that split pane? or do I need to setSize?

Comment: *"I tried adding JSplit pane"*  A split pane divider position can only be set once the component is visible on=screen.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: A very easy workaround, since you extending `JPanel`, instead of giving size to your `JFrame` as in `frame.setSize(1000, 700);` , simply use `frame.pack()`, and what you can do to increase4 the `JPanel`'s size is to override it's [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()). Simply make it return some value that you want it to show in the beginning, then the Layout Manager will do the rest for you, without any trouble :-) +1 for providing the ScreenShot for  help

Comment: What do you mean by "separate view from tabbed pane"? Do you want to take out the view out of the tabbed pane by dragging it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how I solved the problem.

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(new LeftPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, new LeftPanel(), new ViewPanel());
frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(1000, 700);
//frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And this worked out well.